# How to let Android layout files know that a different language is selected

Tags: android, multilingual

I have an App with a Fragment for language selection (FR_LanguageSelection ) that you can see here:

```
package com.example.td.bapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.td.bapp.databinding.FragmentLanguageSelectionBinding;

/**

  Fragment for selecting the language of the app via ImageButtons
 *
 */

public class FR_LanguageSelection extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {



    /*
    String specifying the language of the App
     */
    public static String currentLanguageOfTheApp;
    public static final String LANGUAGE_GERMAN = "German";
    public static final String LANGUAGE_ENGLISH = "English";


    public FR_LanguageSelection() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static FR_LanguageSelection newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FR_LanguageSelection fragment = new FR_LanguageSelection();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    private FragmentLanguageSelectionBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentLanguageSelectionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding.imageButtonGermany.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonUK.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButtonGermany) {
            this.currentLanguageOfTheApp = LANGUAGE_GERMAN;
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate
                    (FR_LanguageSelectionDirections.actionFRLanguageSelectionToFRMenu());


        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButtonUK) {
            this.currentLanguageOfTheApp = LANGUAGE_ENGLISH;
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(FR_LanguageSelectionDirections.actionFRLanguageSelectionToFRMenu());
        }

        }




}
```

So the user can just choose a language and the language is then selected in a static variable that I need in other fragments e.g. for database queries. Basically this works as it should. However, I have created XML-Layout files that use string resources for two different languages. Here is an example of a textView with the string ressource "android:text="@string/size""

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/size"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup_Size"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup_Size"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.50" />
```

Now my question is, how can I tell this layoutfile that it should use the string resource based on the choosen language of the user? Can I do this from the FR_LanguageSelection directly or do I have to do this in the Java class of each Fragment programatically (which I think would not make sense because if so why do I define the string resources)?

I'd appreciate every comment and will be quite thankful for your help.

**Update:**

I just copied the suggested code of "SlothCoding" (see his answer) into my language selection fragment. So when the user has choosen the language German via the ImageButton in the onClick Method the code should be executed (and thus the current language of the app should be set). Unfortunately I get an error by the compiler telling: "Cannot resolve symbol 'activity'". Maybe the error occurs because I use a single-activity-multiple-fragments approach?

Here is the updated class:

```
package com.example.td.bapp;

import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.td.bapp.databinding.FragmentLanguageSelectionBinding;

import java.util.Locale;

/**

  Fragment for selecting the language of the app via ImageButtons
 *
 */

public class FR_LanguageSelection extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {



    /*
    String specifying the language of the App
     */
    public static String currentLanguageOfTheApp;
    public static final String LANGUAGE_GERMAN = "German";
    public static final String LANGUAGE_ENGLISH = "English";


    public FR_LanguageSelection() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static FR_LanguageSelection newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FR_LanguageSelection fragment = new FR_LanguageSelection();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    private FragmentLanguageSelectionBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentLanguageSelectionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding.imageButtonGermany.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonUK.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButtonGermany) {
            this.currentLanguageOfTheApp = LANGUAGE_GERMAN;

            Locale locale;
            locale = new Locale("de", "DE");

            Configuration config = new Configuration(activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            config.setLocale(locale);

            activity.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate
                    (FR_LanguageSelectionDirections.actionFRLanguageSelectionToFRMenu());


        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButtonUK) {
            this.currentLanguageOfTheApp = LANGUAGE_ENGLISH;
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(FR_LanguageSelectionDirections.actionFRLanguageSelectionToFRMenu());
        }

        }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best method to do this, since Android should use locale settings from the phone to set the default language for your application. But I had to do this same thing in my app a year ago and I was forced to use locale configuration inside the app. Here is how it goes. First I ask the user to choose the language he wants and save that inside my `SharedPreferences`. I have a list of languages I create as `JSONObjects` which have

- language_name (ex. English)
- language_code (ex. en)
- language_script (ex. US)

This is how I do this:

```
language_object = new JSONObject();
language_object.put("language_name", "Deutsch");
language_object.put("language_code", "de");
language_object.put("language_script", "LT");
languages.put(language_object);

language_object = new JSONObject();
language_object.put("language_name", "English");
language_object.put("language_code", "en");
language_object.put("language_script", "US");
languages.put(language_object);
```

Now I show the list of these languages using `ListView` and handling clicks inside `LanguageListAdapter`. When the user selects the language he wants I do this inside `ListAdapter`:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layout_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
        convertView = layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_language, parent, false);
    }

    try {

        JSONObject object = _data_set.getJSONObject(position);

        TextView lang_name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.language_name);
        lang_name.setText(object.getString("language_name"));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    SharedPreferences shared_preferences = activity.getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor preferences_editor = shared_preferences.edit();
                    preferences_editor.putString("MY_LANGUAGE", object.toString());
                    preferences_editor.apply();

                    common.setLocale(activity);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoadingActivity.class);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                    activity.finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

And my function `setLocale(Activity activity)` is inside separate class named `common`. I use this class to store functions I would use often throughout my application. And here is how it looks like:

```
public static void setLocale(Activity activity){

    try {
        SharedPreferences shared_preferences = activity.getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = shared_preferences.getString("MY_LANGUAGE", "");

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(language);

        Locale locale;
        locale = new Locale(object.getString("language_code"), object.getString("language_script"));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.setLocale(locale);

        activity.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

This sets language I want and uses `strings.xml` based on `language_code` and `language_script`. So in my `res > values` I have this for example:

- `strings.xml` - default language
- `strings.xml(en-rUS)` - English language
- `strings.xml(de-rLT)` - Custom German language (by custom I mean custom code-script tag)

Now, whenever the user selects, let's say the German language, I save "de-LT" as a code for language and use it inside `setLocale` so that the app can read from that `strings.xml` resource.

---

**EDIT:** How to create `strings.xml` for each language?

So, to do this you need to first go to the `res > values` folder. There you will have your default `strings.xml` file. This one is used when you don't have defined `strings.xml` for users' locale phone settings. By default, this should be English if the app can be used internationally, the reason is simple and you probably know why.

In this `strings.xml` you define all your strings you are using with your application, and you do it like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TempProject</string>

    <string name="Size">Size</string>

</resources>
```

Now, you want to create a translation for, let's say, German and Croatian language. You need to do this. **Right-click on values folder > New > Values Resource File**

[image]

Now a new window will open and you need to fill it like this:

[image]

So, let's go slowly, field by field.

- File name: `strings.xml` - Same name as default file
- Directory name: `values-de-rDE` - This defines directory name with German country code, that is how the compiler will know from which file to read the string you defined. If you don't know country codes you can simply use `Available qualifiers` and select *Locale > From Language section choose "de: German" > From Specific Region Only choose what you want, in my case I used "DE: Germany"*. This will automatically generate the same directory name as I did above:

[image]

Now you have new `strings.xml` file but it has aditional tag on the right like this `(de-rDE)`. Now inside that file just define the same string like in default `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="Size">Größe</string>

</resources>
```

Now you can see that I don't have a defined string for app name inside this resource file and you'll get a warning for this. When you go to default strings.xml you'll see this:

[image]

So just make sure that you have defined same strings in all of the files from `strings.xml` files.

I followed everything from above and added more translations for Croatian and also for English besides the default file. So, now I have this:

[image]

Now you can use my function `setLocale()` and inside this line just provide country code:

```
Locale locale;
locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
Configuration config = new Configuration(activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
Locale.setDefault(locale);
config.setLocale(locale);

activity.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

You can see for the second argument I only typed "DE" and not "rDE". This will set locale to german language and your app will use `strings.xml (de-rDE)` file for string resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer SlothCoding. Basically I forgot to mention that there will be different users at the same device, so I think I can't use the shared preferences. Further, with your approach one would have to implement the language specific displaying of the UI elements in every fragment altough I have used string ressources when creating the layout. So what use is it then to use these string resources if I anyways have to set the text of the UI elements programatically?

Comment: You don't have to set text programmatically, just use string resources as it is. This locale sets configuration so it is using the strings.xml you want. So I have like 8 languages inside my app and I have 9 strings.xml, one default, and others with specific language code - language script tag. When I set locale configuration using those codes and tags it automatically reads from that strings.xml and I use string resource to show text in my views. If you have different users you can again use SharedPreferences, just apply a bit different logic based on which user is using at that moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer SlothCoding. I still do not understand how the layout then knows which resource file to choose. Let's say I have a textview tv and I want to set the text via String resource. So it would be: tv.setText(getString(R.string.Size)).

Comment: Each strings.xml have the same ID for each string, but a different value. So, you will have let's say two strings.xml, one for English one for german. And both will have <string name="Size">VALUE</string>. So when you choose the locale for German it will go in german strings.xml and take value from Size, the same will happen for every language you have. First, learn how these things work. Check this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Comment: Thanks SlothCoding for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I know how to define those String resources in XML files (I have already done this for about 100 strings). You wrote "So when you choose the locale for German ". This is exactly my question. How can I do this? How can I tell the layout 'use the German string'?

Comment: Like I told you in the answer. Setting configuration locale like I did in function setLocale. I don't know how you created those strings, you need to understand that you have to create a bunch of strings.xml files inside the values folder, then they will group into one strings folder which will contain strings.xml which is default one, and also for each language you need to have one strings.xml also, but this time you will add country code and country script so it will be created as the new file inside values but with the same name - strings.xml. Refer to link I sent you to understand this.

Comment: Thanks SlothCoding for your further comment. So I just have to put the following code into the Fragment for language selection:
"        Locale locale;
        locale = new Locale(object.getString("language_code"), object.getString("language_script"));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.setLocale(locale);"

Comment: @VanessaF I edited my answer, please read it again. I just described step by step what you need to do. I hope it helps, if you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot SlothCoding for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. As told before, creating the XML file is not the problem and I had done this before. The problem is how to tell the layout file the currently selected language of one user. I inserted your suggested code into my Fragment but it yields an error message "Cannot resolve symbol 'activity'". I wrote an Update on my question with the new code. I assume that the error occurs because I do not use an activity but a fragment for the language selection

Comment: wherever is "activity" used, just use "getActivity()" in Fragment, this should probably work.

Comment: Thanks a lot SlothCoding for your great help. Now it seems to work as intended :-). I really appreciate your effort. I upvoted and accepted your answer.

Comment: Maybe one follow up question: If I want to set it back to english (default) can I just alter the code by using the command: "locale = new Locale("en", "EN");"?

Comment: @VanessaF Well, I would suggest creating additional strings.xml (en-rUS) for English, even if your default one is the English language. The default one will be called if a better option is not found. Let's say your locale is in Italian but you don't have Italian strings, default will be called. So just create another with (en-rUS) tag and copy strings from default strings.xml. Then you can use new Locale("en", "EN");

Comment: Thanks SlothCoding for your answer. Basically I tried my suggested code without creating one for english explicitly and it seems to work.

Comment: Yeah, it will work, as I said. If you don't have one with that tag it will go for default. It's just what you prefer the most and how you want to do it. Anyway, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your further answer. So said that I should create an string.xml for English. So would this mean I have 3 XML file: One default, one English and one German? What would be the difference between the default one and the English one?

Comment: Nothing actually, it will be pretty much the same except it would have a tag (en-rUS) let's say. This is just for code readability so when someone is looking at your code can say "okay, he is setting English now"

Comment: Hi SlothCoding, altough your suggested approach works for almost all fragments that I have, I experience a wrong behaviour when using a bottomNavigationBar. Here I use an item in the XML layout file with the attribute "android:title = "@string/Language" />". However, when choosing another language the displayed text in the BottomNavigationBar does not change. Do you have any idea why this is the case? So basically I would like to tell the BottomNavigationBar to choose the german word (if German was choosen as the language). I'd appreicate any further comments from you

Comment: @VanessaF I am not sure why is that but I had strange behavior while using WebView as a child in my layout. Right after I worked with web view inside my code I just called function setLocale() again and it worked fine. I googled for like a week to solve this issue but I guess it's something that needs to be fixed by Google and I couldn't find a solution only a bunch of people with the same problem. Maybe try to google something like "String resource not working with bottom navigation bar" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks SlothCoding for your comment. Unfortunately I could not find anything about this issue. I will try to ask it here in Stackoverflow